# Nested lists in SCSS inside of a @function

Tags: css, function, sass, each

Trying to figure out why this code isn't working as I'd like it to. If I declare relatively the same function in a @mixin, it works perfectly; but since I'm currently developing a micro-framework, I'd like to keep this as a @function, as it will be reused in the code multiple times. This code below is obviously stripped down, but hopefully you will get what I'm needing the @function to @return based on what $type is passed.

```
$config:
desktop 16 1280px,
laptop 12 960px,
tablet 8 640px,
mobile 4 320px;

@function run($type) {
    @each $list in $config {
        $alias: nth($list, 1);
        $columns: nth($list, 2);
        $break: nth($list, 3);

        @if $type == $alias {
            @return $break;
        } @else if $type == $columns {
            @return $columns;
        } @else if $type == $break {
            @return $alias;
        } @else { @return false; }
    }
} 

@debug run(desktop);

// returns '1280px' in command line, like it should.

@debug run(mobile);

// returns 'false'
// it should return '320px', as with 'desktop'?
```

It's probably an easy fix, but if possible, explain why it keeps @returning 'false' on everything except 'desktop'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `return: false;` out of the `@each` loop, otherwise the function will try to return false on each iteration where it doesn't find a match (i.e. break out of the loop).

```
@function run($type) {
    @each $list in $config {
        $alias: nth($list, 1);
        $columns: nth($list, 2);
        $break: nth($list, 3);

        @if $type == $alias {
            @return $break;
        } @else if $type == $columns {
            @return $columns;
        } @else if $type == $break {
            @return $alias;
        }
    }
    @return false;
}
```